# Checkmk Dynamic service monitoring without any script

Tags: check-mk

I am monitoring JPM services with script placed in check_mk_agent/local . do we have any other way by which we can monitor java related services without any script deployment in checkmk agent.

I have kept list of services and script in this location : /usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of integrations that you can facilitate to monitor Java applications through Jolokia with Checkmk: https://checkmk.com/integrations?tags=java

Additionally, here is a forum post discussing troubleshooting this: https://forum.checkmk.com/t/jolokia-implementation/28203

Hope this helps!